# Which input embeddings are learned during pre-training in BERT? What about during fine-tuning?

Tags: natural-language-processing, transformer, bert

I was reading the 2019 BERT paper and they mention how they use wordpieces that are then represented as the sum of token embeddings, segment embeddings, and positional embeddings. What is unclear to me is whether the token, segment and positional embeddings are all learned during pre-training AND whether they are modified during fine-tuning.

### Pre-Training:

- **Sentence Embeddings:** The paper says that the sentence embeddings are learned during pre-training ("we add a learned embedding to every token indicating whether it belongs to sentence A or sentence B"). **am pretty confident about this.**
- **Positional Embeddings:** The paper does not say whether the positional embeddings are learned during pre-training. However, BERT relies on the transformer architecture from the "Attention Is All You Need" pa[er and I believe the positional embeddings in THAT paper are learned during what would pre-training for the BERT model. **- Not so confident about this.**
- **Token Embeddings:** I'm guessing the token embeddings aren't learned during pre-training but before pre-training. Specifically, I hypothesize that the authors simply use the word piece embeddings approach to break up sentences into word "pieces" AND map each of these pieces to numbers, but this mapping is not modified during pre-training. **- I'm very uncertain about this.**

**Are positional embeddings and token embeddings learned during pre-training?**

### Fine-Tuning:

Essentially the same question but for fine-tuning: are these embeddings typically modified during fine-tuning?